# Send multiple objects between threads using invoke in c#

Tags: c#, invoke

I'm having problems with passing loaded data from one thread to another to add the data to the form. I added another object into "var obj = new object[] { names }" and got "Parameter count mismatch". I'd still prefer to pass "Clients" and "Messages" from "LoadData()" in the second thread to "UpdateFormMethod()" in the first one, but I have no idea how to do it. I'd be grateful if anyone could help me with this problem.

Here's the important part of the code within one class:

```
private readonly Thread _thread;
    public readonly Loader Loader = new Loader();
    public Dictionary<string, Client> Clients;
    public Dictionary<string, Message> Messages;
    private bool _stopData = false;
    public delegate void UpdateForm(object data);
    public UpdateForm MyDelegate;

    public Fcon() {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyDelegate = new UpdateForm(UpdateFormMethod);
        _thread = new Thread(LoadData);
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void UpdateFormMethod(object data) {
        foreach (var str in ((IEnumerable<string>)data).Where(str => !fcon_container_users_list.Items.Contains(str))) {
            fcon_container_users_list.Items.Insert(0, str);
        }
    }

    public void LoadData() {
        while (!_stopData) {
            Clients = Loader.GetClients(Operator);
            Messages = Loader.GetMessages(Operator);
            var status = Loader.SetStatus(Operator);
            var names = new string[Clients.Count];
            var x = 0;
            foreach (var kvp in Clients) {
                names[x] = "user_" + kvp.Value.id_fcon_client;
                x++;
            }
            var obj = new object[] { names };
            this.Invoke(this.MyDelegate, obj);    
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    public void StopData() {
        _stopData = true;
    }
```

Comment: Please be more explicit about what your question is. (1) What exactly did you do to "add some other object"? (2) By "I'd still prefer to ...", do you mean "My question is how I can ...", or is the actual question something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're not entirely clear where the signature is coming from. It's your own delegate - if you want to change the signature, just change the signature of the delegate and the method implementing it:

```
public delegate void UpdateForm(IEnumerable<string> data, int foo);

...

public void UpdateFormMethod(IEnumerable<string> data, int foo) {
    foreach (var str in data.Where(str => 
               !fcon_container_users_list.Items.Contains(str))) {
        fcon_container_users_list.Items.Insert(0, str);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var obj = new object[] { names, someIntVariable };
this.Invoke(this.MyDelegate, obj);
```

Or more simply:

```
this.Invoke(this.MyDelegate, names, someIntVariable);
```

I'd probably use the existing `Action<T>`, `Action<T1, T2>` delegates rather than creating new ones though OR T Func<T1 [,T2]> if you require a return type.

Comment: Thank you very much! This way it works perfectly. And thanks about the advice about Action<T>, I'm gonna read about it. It's my first week of C# and I need to learn fast.

Answer (score -1):

you are passing an object [] in but you should only pass in object.

To send it in just cast it as object i.e.

```
this.Invoke(this.MyDelegate, (object)obj);
```

and cast it back inside the method. The reason they specified object as the parameter type is that it allows them not to have to specify many many signatures I think

Comment: Why would you want to create an array for this then cast all the bits back in the method, when it's a lot simpler just to change the delegate type?

Comment: Point taken @JonSkeet - I thought it was a system defined delegate. Though given the signature of the delegate my answer still stands :) Nice score by the way :) I cannot argue with the 'Skeet'!